# Add repeating tasks using stock calendar

Tags: calendar, to-do-list

### Is it possible to have repeating tasks using the stock calender program?

Sometimes I have a task I want to show up each day for a month or something, but I don't want to have to stick with a photocopy machine and handwriting a task list when I have a Galaxy Note 3, running android 4.4.2 kitkat. I don't want to have to root and use questionable programs, just stock android. However, I don't mind, but would really rather avoid, doing something on a computer such as a Perl script and then syncing with wifi or or pushing through usb. I would think that the calendar program would have this feature, but I can't find it anywhere.

The event-type in the calender program can handle repeating events, but not task-type. Events just fill up blocks of time, I want the ability to check off a task, so events wont work.

Comment: Well, I'd say that's what [Todo Lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo) are for? Though often "joined" with calendars PIM-style, they are a bit different from calendar events – despite of them being possible to store within iCal format.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the list - I will go through it and see if any of those have features that solve the issue. Could I make one iCal file that adds all the repeats by specifying the duration?

Comment: I've never played with Tasks in iCal – but as they have a specific definition block in that format, it should be technically possible. After all, that's how some CalDAV Sync apps deal with ToDo-Apps ;)